# Thinkpad T61 won't wake from sleep / suspend 13.04

Tags: suspend, thinkpad, sleep

My laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad T61 with intel graphics card running 13.04.  I'm pretty sure that when my battery gets too low, the laptop suspends itself, but when i plug it back in, it won't come on.  Actually, if I've been playing music or video, i can hear the sound, often glitching and skipping, but there is absolutely no response from the monitor.  The indicator lights come on, as if the computer is running, but no buttons work provoke a response, except when I hold the power button down for an extended time to shut the computer off.
Please help: almost everything else on the computer works perfectly.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. Upon reboot, I went into Ubuntu Advanced and changed linux boot kernel from 3.8.x to 3.5.x and I have no issue when rebooting.  Hope this helps you as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Nouveau display driver to be the problem
Fix I did:

Go into software & Updates (search for this app with the Ubuntu "search your computer and online sources" top left menu, Ubuntu icon). Then go to "Additional Drivers" tab. Switch from "Using X.Org X server -Nouveau display driver..." to Using NVIDIA binary Xorg driver.. 310 (proprietary tested/) version and apply.

On the next reboot it suspended fine and has been working great ever since

Comment: This fixed the same issue for me (T61 with Nvidia Quadro NVS 140m), switched to the latest available Nvidia driver (331.38 at time of writing)

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar sounding issues with hibernate.  I've installed Gnome Ubuntu 13.04 on my T61 and tried to hibernate using TuxOnIce.  It hibernates and resumes ok, but on resume the screen is frozen.  I can see the screen as it was when I hibernated, but nothing moves, not even the mouse.  I can't even CTRL-ALT-F2 to get to another session.

Exactly the same thing happens with suspend.

I had no problems hibernating with Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 (although sometimes gnome-shell used to hang on resume, I could always <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> to another session and kill -9 gnome-shell to recover)

My T61 is a little different to the original poster's, it has an Nvidia NV140m rather than intel graphics.  (I may also mention that I use encrypted swap, as [per these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap))

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case wasn't the wifi but the (open source) nouveau display driver. Replaced it with the (closed source) nvidia driver. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried adding "modprob -r iwl4965" when lid closes and "modprob iwl4965" when it opens. Seems to fix the problem (maybe your wifi module is iwlwifi).