# Waking up from Suspend

Tags: 16.04, suspend

Pretty weird situation. My Lenovo PC with Ubuntu 16.04 based on AMD gpu cannot resume from suspension, and yet leaving the cpu and the fan spinning all along, causing extreme heating problem. It's been frustrating me since the installation a about a month ago. Is there anyone who knows what's going on here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: With pmutils installed, what happens if you try suspending with `sudo pm-suspend`?

Comment: What model is your computer?

Comment: @NickWeinberg Thinkpad E550

Comment: Possibly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/489912/thinkpad-does-not-wake-from-sleep-14-04

Comment: This blog post says upgrading the kernel solved the issue: http://lifepluslinux.blogspot.com/2016/04/ubuntu-1604-wont-wake-up-from-suspend.html

Comment: There are also indications that a BIOS update from Lenovo has fixed the issue: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-11e-Windows-E-and-Edge/E540-Suspend-Resume-failure/m-p/2048067#M22103

Comment: @NickWeinberg Should it be done on Windows or not?

Comment: @JamesWong I assume you're asking about the BIOS update? I believe it's easiest to install from windows, but there are ways to do it from Linux... just google "lenovo bios update linux" or whatever for instructions. The BIOS update file should be available to download from the Lenovo Support site

Comment: @NickWeinberg such a great help. I'll give it a go.